# Not able to print a string with "/0" at end

Tags: python

I have the string:

```
s="abc\0"
```

and I would like to see that output with the `\0` at the end.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? any ideas on your own?

Comment: Do you mean with `\0` at the end?

Comment: Do you have a string consisting of a backslash and a zero or a string ending in a null character?

Comment: I think he meant "abc/0" which is printable

Comment: If you do `print('abc\0')`, it will print "abc" plus a null byte to your terminal.  The null byte is not printable, so you won't see anything.

Comment: @TimRoberts that's exactly my point. Is  there any way to make it visible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\0'` is the null character in this context.

To make it be interpreted as \0, you have to write it as `'\\0`', or `s = "abc\\0"` in the full string.

Comment: you can also change the "\" to a "/"

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege not sure what you mean by this, since `'\\0'` is not the same as `'/\0'`.

Comment: You both have described three very different things.  At this point, we don't know what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @csjh I meant "abc/0" :) not "abc\/0"

Comment: Adding \\0 solved my problem! thanks everyone

Comment: OK, but you should know that means something VERY different than what you asked.  If you really want the string "backslash zero", then that's exactly the right way.